# Error 505 Getaway Time Out Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

Performing severe methods to analyze text in rails. The problem is, when the user loads a text file on the server is processing it (there is a search keyword rankings are calculated every word and many others) are obtained as a result, that while the server processes the text, it can not even display a page to a friend users and is 505 Gateway Time Out Error.

Answer (score 1):

A gateway timeout error means that your application is taking too long to return a result, and  the gateway/proxy which routes the connection to your application has given up. Either increase the timeout on your gateway, or (much better in the long term) consider moving your processor-intensive task to a background thread/process.

Comment: Tell me how to perform highly loaded methods put in ruby in the background?

Comment: All is good, it is true, but it is returned as the result of the function, without using a database. Nebhodimo simply return the result of a function, it returns the same JID) JID How to get a result?) Something I can not figure it out ..